# Lottie Animation not appearing in CardView?

Tags: android, react-native, lottie

I am having a hard time displaying a Lottie animation where I want it. So far, I am able to display it outside like this:

```
<View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
   <Animation
         progress={this.state.progress}
         source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}

         />
     <ScrollView>

        <FlatList

          data={ this.state.dataSource}

          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


          renderItem={({item}) => <View>


          <View style={styles.coverContainer}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{uri:`http://www.example.com/img/123.jpg`}}
        style={styles.coverImage}
      >
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>

    </View>


          </View>


        }

        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        removeClippedSubviews

     />

     <FlatList

       data={ this.state.image}

       ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


       renderItem={({item}) => <View>


       <RkCard style={{width:'75%', marginLeft: 50, marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}}>

         <View rkCardContent>

         </View>
         <View rkCardFooter>
         
           <Text> Notes</Text>
         </View>

       </RkCard>


       </View>


     }

     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
     removeClippedSubviews

  />


     </ScrollView>
     </View>
```

This setup just allows the animation to play in the background while the content is on top of it. I want the animation to play inside the content like this:

```
<View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
   
     <ScrollView>

        <FlatList

          data={ this.state.dataSource}

          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


          renderItem={({item}) => <View>


          <View style={styles.coverContainer}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{uri:`http://www.example.com/img/123.jpg`}}
        style={styles.coverImage}
      >
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>

    </View>


          </View>


        }

        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        removeClippedSubviews

     />

     <FlatList

       data={ this.state.image}

       ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


       renderItem={({item}) => <View>


       <RkCard style={{width:'75%', marginLeft: 50, marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}}>

         <View rkCardContent>

         </View>
         <View rkCardFooter>
           <Animation
         progress={this.state.progress}
         source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}

         /> // Animation here
           <Text> Notes</Text>
         </View>

       </RkCard>


       </View>


     }

     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
     removeClippedSubviews

  />


     </ScrollView>
     </View>
```

I tried putting the animation in other places and I still get the same result. My conclusion is that it has something to do with ScrollView.

The problem isn't with ScrollView, it's with cardview, and it's causing the animation to go off screen.